# Remove escape sequences

Tags: c++, escaping, sequence

I'm trying to make an application that control its self location. I use this code for full path.

```
char ownPth[MAX_PATH]; 
HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
GetModuleFileName(hModule,ownPth, (sizeof(ownPth)));
```

But I can't control it if it is location that I want. Because I need to use \ int if statement. So the compiler thinks it is a escape sequence. How can I remove it. I'm using  dev c++ 4.9.9.2

Comment: you can write `\\` to get single backslash in a character or string literal. but it's not at all clear that that is your problem. how about, u now, a **concrete example**?

Comment: If using C++11, you can use `R"delimiter(My\Text\with\back\slashes)delimiter";` and it will be: `My\Text\with\back\slashes`

Comment: You may need to "escape" the backslashs: C:\\Users\\Thomas\\Programming.  Or use forward slashes: C:/Users/Thomas/Programming.